# 'pos_start' not defined in a sea of stuff I don't quite understand

Tags: python

So, I'm working on making a programming language as a fun project, so I decided to follow this tutorial. When I was finished with the first episode, it said this error:

```
Name_Error: name 'pos_start' is not defined
```

Here is the code (sorry, its very long)

```
###########
#CONSTANTS#
###########

DIGITS = "123456789"

########
#ERRORS#
########

class Error:
  def __init__(self, pos_start, pos_end, error_name, details):
    self.pos_start = pos_start
    self.pos_end = pos_end
    self.error_name = error_name
    self.details = details

  def as_string(self):
    result = f'{self.error_name}: {self.details}'
    result += f'File {self.pos_star.fn}, line {self.pos_start.ln + 1}'
    return result
class IllegalCharError(Error):
  def __init__(self, pos_start, pos_end, details):
    super().__init__(pos_start, pos_end, "Sorry, dude, but we don't support that character you typed :(   ", details)

##########
#POSITION#
##########

class Position:
  def __init__(self, idx, ln, col, fn, ftxt):
    self.idx = idx
    self.ln = ln
    self.col = col
    self.fn = fn
    self.ftxt = ftxt

  def advance(self, current_char):
    self.idx += 1
    self.col += 1

    if current_char == "\n":
      self.ln += 1
      self.col = 0

    return self

  def copy(self):
    return Position(self.idx, self.ln, self.col, self.fn, self.ftxt)

########
#TOKENS#
########
TT_INT = "TT_INT"
TT_FLOAT = "FLOAT"
TT_PLUS = "PLUS"
TT_MINUS = "MINUS"
TT_MUL = "MUL"
TT_DIV = "DIV"
TT_LPAREN = "LPAREN"
TT_RPAREN = "RPAREN"

class Token:
  def __init__(self, type_, value=None):
    self.type = type_
    self.value = value

  def __repr__(self):
    if self.value: return f'{self.type}:{self.value}'
    return f'{self.type}'

#######
#LEXER#
#######

class Lexer:
  def __init__(self, fn, text):
    self.fn = fn
    self.text = text
    self.pos = Position(-1, 0, -1, fn, text)
    self.current_char = None
    self.advance()

  def advance(self):
    self.pos.advance(self.current_char)
    self.current_char = self.text[self.pos.idx] if self.pos.idx < len(self.text) else None

  def make_tokens(self):
    tokens = []

    while self.current_char != None:
      if self.current_char in ' \t':
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char in DIGITS:
        tokens.append(self.make_number())
      elif self.current_char == "+":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_PLUS))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "-":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_MINUS))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "*":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_MUL))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "/":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_DIV))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "(":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_LPAREN))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == ")":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_RPAREN))
        self.advance()
      else:
        self.pos.copy()
        char = self.current_char
        self.advance()
        return [], IllegalCharError(pos_start, self.pos, "'" + char +"'")


    return tokens, None

  def make_number(self):
    num_str = ""
    dot_count = 0

    while self.current_char != None and self.current_char in DIGITS + ".":
      if self.current_char == ".":
        if dot_count == 1: break
        dot_count += 1
        num_str += "."
      else:
        num_str += self.current_char
      self.advance()

    if dot_count == 0:
      return Token(TT_INT, int(num_str))
    else:
      return Token(TT_FLOAT, float(num_str))

#####
#RUN#
#####

def run(fn, text):
  lexer = Lexer(fn, text)
  tokens, error = lexer.make_tokens()

  return tokens, error
```

Please note I suck at python, so I don't understand most of this other than a little bit of classes, since I'm following a tutorial.
So, can someone smarter than me please help me find the error? Thanks.
EDIT: Closed! I found the error on the tutorial maker's github page for this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us the full traceback?

Comment: the full error, you mean?

Comment: `pos_start` is a member of `Error` not `Lexer` and even if you were referencing it in the right class, you'd still need to use `self.pos_start`.

Answer (score 1):

Was there a stack trace that went along with that error message?  If there was, then that should tell you right where the problem is.

Searching through your code for the symbol in question, I see only one place this can be coming from.  That is this line:

```
return [], IllegalCharError(pos_start, self.pos, "'" + char +"'")
```

in the `make_tokens` method.  I don't see anywhere that that symbol is being defined such that it has a value at that point in the code.  All other references to that symbol have matching definitions that say that the symbol should be defined before that reference is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_tokens(self):
    tokens = []
    while self.current_char != None:
      if self.current_char in ' \t':
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char in DIGITS:
        tokens.append(self.make_number())
      elif self.current_char == "+":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_PLUS))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "-":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_MINUS))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "*":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_MUL))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "/":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_DIV))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == "(":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_LPAREN))
        self.advance()
      elif self.current_char == ")":
        tokens.append(Token(TT_RPAREN))
        self.advance()
      else:
        self.pos.copy()
        char = self.current_char
        self.advance()
        return [], IllegalCharError(pos_start, self.pos, "'" + char +"'")
```

I believe it is because you are calling `pos_start` here without using `self`.  Let me know if that fixes it. Use `self.pos_start`, that is defined.

Comment: I thought of this because I wanted to be able to tell the OP what he might want to do to fix the problem.  I don't think `self.pos_start` is defined at that point in the code either.  That code is in a method in the `Lexer` class.  If you look at that class's `__init__` method, you won't see `self.pos_start` being set.  I don't see it being set anywhere else in that class's methods either.  I can't guess what is supposed to go in that spot.